# Piping back resulting stream from split remote commands

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar, pipe

I'm trying to perform the following:
(1) generating data on my local workstation
(2) piping this data (huge amount!) once to my remote speedy server
(3) performing two separate operations on this data, which generate (simplified) two separate output files
(4) piping these output files (somehow) back to my local workstation

The problem is that, having split the pipe stream on the server's side into two independent processes, I cannot see an elegant way of reducing them back into one return stream.

What would work, actually, is creating two separate output files on the server side, tarring them and copying them (manually or in a separate operation) back to my workstation.

What would work, too, is splitting the pipe stream already on the workstation's side and piping two separate streams to the server. This would induce doubled network load and should be avoided at all costs.

I would prefer not to save any data on the server. Is there any way to add two streams to one tar file simultaneously? Or any other idea I can't find atm?

Best regards

Comment: How are you moving the data across the network?  Telnet, scp, http, ??  Are the server processes generating line-oriented output?

Comment: The data is transferred via ssh within a pipe, such as: <generate_data> | ssh myserver "do_something" | cat > output.data. The server is generating simple output character streams.

Comment: does the output data have to be joined one after the other or can it be mixed (by line)?

Comment: If I get your question right: the output date must be separated from each other in two separate files.